# Bob is 16. Grandma is 100. When will bob be half her age assuming both never die?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Bob is 16. Grandma is 100. When will bob be half her age assuming both never die?

Hi I would love an answer to this. Is there also an equation? Iv been trying to wrap my head around this all day. Thanks!

Comment: An alternate way to Sanath's method (which works fine) is to think, "How much older than Bob is Grandma?"  That will never change.  So when will Bob's age equal that?

Comment: Solve for x you mean? If not then im not too sure

Comment: You can solve for x using Sanath's equation (which is a good example of how to write a word problem as an equation).  Alternately, you can think, Grandma is 84 years older than Bob.  So when Bob is 84 Grandma will be 84+84.  Which will be in 68 years.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be the number of years after which Bob is half of his grandma's age. Then, we have:
$$16+x=\dfrac{100+x}{2}$$
Can you solve this?